How to disable s1309 (Disable warning when suppressing warnings) in Sonarcloud?
My company uses Sonarcloud analysis within our Azure DevOps projects and pipelines. We are allowed to use the SuppressMessage attribute to suppress certain types of errors. Sadly, we need to suppress s1309 (Disable warning when suppressing warnings) as well, which disables the error about using SuppressMessage, which means we need to disable s1309 everywhere we suppress something else, or suppress it in every solution with a GlobalSuppressions file. I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to disable the s1309 error from within Sonarcloud (for all projects). In our opinion you don't suppress and it throws the 1309 error, or you are allowed to suppress and don't throw the 1309.
Hoping anyone knows how to do this. Unfortunately I can't browse the Sonarcloud settings, this is something our lead architect manages.

You can disable it using
#pragma warning disable S3881

In case you want to do it for all projects you need to modify the rules in Sonarcloud settings.

sorry, my question wasn't clear enough (updated it). I want to disable it in Sonarcloud for all projects to come.

Got it, thanks for clarification. It seems like in this case the only way to disable it is to modify the rules through Sonarcloud settings
